# Trouble finding certain places using Here Places autosuggest

Tags: javascript, rest, here-api

I have implemented the Here Places API for autocomplete suggestions. However a lot of places aren't showing up unless you type in the address. For example if I search for "Depannage 2ade" or different variant of that name, I dont get any results. However if I type in the physical address, I can get a result.

I figured this was because there wasn't enough information on the place in the Here app however I went on mapcreator.here.com to add information on the place in hope of adding it but I found that by typing in the address, in the map creator the name is already there. So I was wondering if there was maybe a parameter missing from my request that were preventing some places to show or maybe something that I'm doing wrong.

```
$.ajax({
            url: "https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/autosuggest" +
                "?app_id=KEY" +
                "&app_code=KEY",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                q: val,
                at: companyGeo.replace(" ",""),
                size: '5',
                result_types: 'address,place',
                addressFilter: 'countryCode=fra'
            },
            type: "GET",

});
```

Basically I used address and places as filter and I search within the country of France. I can only find the place by typing the address and not the name. This isn't the case for ALL places but for many it is, and I find that odd since in the mapcreator they do have a place name entered.

Comment: Hi, would you please give more information what you want to search , and what is the address you want to search?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the new Places base URL:
https://places.ls.hereapi.com which uses the latest authentication method (apiKey). So retry your query with this new API URL.

Note also that the cit environment is only for testing and should not be used in production.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/dev_guide/common/request-cit-environment-rest.html

https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/dev_guide/topics/request-constructing.html